# Difference time calculation float and double on OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I'm using AMD GPU and `OpenCL 1.2`. All my calculations use double variables. Who has researched this topic, can you tell me please, is there any point in rewriting everything on float? Will there be a big difference in the calculation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much faster floats are vs doubles depends on the exact hardware. Certain professional grade AMD GPUs are specifically optimised for doubles (e.g. AMD FirePro 9100). On such hardware, `double` multiplications are half as fast as `float` multiplications, and addition is the same speed.

On most regular consumer hardware (most Radeons), the difference is about 1/16 and 1/8, respectively. There are also some devices which are in between, at about 1/4 and 1/2 speed for floats.

You can get the exact details in AMD's [OpenCL Optimisation Guide](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_Optimization_Guide.pdf), section 2.7.1 "Instruction Bandwidths".

Basically, unless you've specifically bought a device optimised for doubles, you will probably see a huge speed improvement moving to floats, assuming you don't actually need the extra precision or can compensate for it easily.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll have to rewrite the code.

Comment: I would suggest to introduce a real_t typedef in your code that can be configured at compile time to be either float or double, e.g. https://github.com/noma/hexciton_benchmark/blob/5c4ee1f627a7422f527d4b86a923a0543f7b3f4b/include/kernel/common.cl#L20